# iOS: memory footprint of local variable defined in methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I need to have a few hard coded collection data (ie `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`), and I'm wondering what the memory footprint is it like, for example,

```
- (NSArray *)getDataA
{
    NSArray *data = @[ @{@"key": @"value"} ];
    return data;
}
```

And the actual data is way more than the key-value in the above code.

I guess the local variables are stored on stack and the actual value are in heap, but before calling `getDataA`, do they occupy any memory space?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have MBs the size is not really important. Like all optimizations: don't. Do the most clear implementation and then measure.

Comment: The memory size in your example is O(n).  As Zaph mentioned, what the actual MB of the array is doesn't matter until you are running out of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that a structure such as in the question is created by code executing at runtime, they will not be static. Constant NSStrings are the exception and possibly a few other special cases like some NSNumbers.

Unless you have MBs the size is not really important. Like all optimizations: don't. Do the most clear implementation and then measure.